# How to make winrestview work in vim script

Tags: vim

I am writing a small script to "zoom" on a split in vim so that it takes the whole screen.
However, the cursor position is lost during the resizing operations, and my attempt to restore it with `winsaveview` and `winrestview` fail. Any idea why ?
Many thanks.

```
" maximize split
let t:maximized = "false"
function MaximizeSplit()
    let l:position = winsaveview()
    if t:maximized == "false"
        let t:maximized = "true"
        vertical resize
        resize
    elseif t:maximized == "true"
        let t:maximized = "false"
        execute "normal \<C-W>\="
    endif
    call winrestview(l:position)
endfunction
```